Counting "algebraic numbers" inside square matrices over Q.
Let $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ be the set of all $n$-by-$n$ matrices with rational coefficients. I would like to know the percentage/proportion, inside $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ or $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$, of all matrices that can appear in some $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra embedding of a number field $K\hookrightarrow M_n(\mathbb{Q})$, where by ''number field'' I mean a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let us say that such matrices "come from number fields", or simply, are "algebraic numbers".
Proprosition. $M \in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ comes from a number field if and only if its minimal polynomial $\mu_M(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible.
Proof. A matrix $M$ comes from a number field if and only if the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $K_M := \mathbb{Q}[M]$ generated by $M$ inside $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is a field.
It is clear that $K_M \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/\mu_M(x)$, which is a field if and only if $\mu_M(x)$ is a maximal ideal, if and only if $\mu_M(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial. $\square$
Example. If $n=2$, then
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has its characteristic polynomial being $$\chi_M(x) = x^2 - \mathrm{Tr}(M) x + \det(M) = x^2 - (a+d)x + (ad-bc)$$ and we know $\mu_M(x) \mid \chi_M(x)$.
Thus, the minimal polynomial $\mu_M(x)$ is reducible if and only if $\mu_M(x)=\chi_M(x)$ which

either splits into the product of two distinct linear factors, which exactly means that the discriminant $$\Delta = \mathrm{Tr}(M)^2 - 4\det(M) = (a+d)^2 - 4(ad-bc) = (a-d)^2 + 4bc$$ is a nonzero square in $\mathbb{Q}^\times$,

or is of the form $(x-\lambda)^2$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$, which means that $M$ is conjugate
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix}
$$
over $\mathbb{Q}$.


So, the matrices coming from number fields is the complement in $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ of the union of the two subsets above.
Questions.
(i) Does the set of  matrices coming from number fields have a density in $\mathbb{Q}^4 = M_2(\mathbb{Q})$?
(ii) If there is no good answer to (i) because $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have a Haar measure, what if we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by the p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ which is locally compact and hence has a good Haar measure?
Or, we can replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$?
(iii) Of course, it would be great if this question can be answered in general for arbitrary $n$...?

When you say "the embedding of a number field $K \hookrightarrow M_n(\mathbb Q)$", are you assuming that $K$ is of degree $n$ and using the embedding via its regular representation, or is there some other canonical embedding, or do you mean an embedding?

@LSpice Oh, I just mean an embedding. K can have any degree dividing n, I think. Thank you for pointing out the imprecision.

@J.S. I mean, in that case $\mu_M$ is irreducible. I just claim that when $\mu_M$ is reducible, it should be the same as $\chi_M$, in the $n=2$ case.

Re, since $M_{n'}(\mathbb Q)$ embeds in $M_n(\mathbb Q)$ whenever we have $n' \le n$, we can get any number field of degree $\le n$, not just of degree dividing $n$.  (I think it is also good to pay attention to the subtleties that @J.S. points out; as they mention, your definitions in (i)–(iii) exclude scalar matrices, which I think they shouldn't according to your definition of "comes from a number field".)

@LSpice Thank you for mentioning the subtleties; you are right. But for the embeddings, I would like $\iota: K \hookrightarrow M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ to be a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra embedding, that is to say, the image of $K$ contains the scalar matrices $\mathbb{Q}\cdot \mathrm{id}$. I think this puts the divisibility constraint on the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$: the minimal polynomial of a primitive element $\alpha \in K$ agrees with the minimal polynomial of $\iota(K) \in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$, which is thus irreducible. This shows $\chi_{\iota(K)} = \mu_{\iota(K)}^d$ for some integer d.

Re, right, sorry, I was thinking of ring homomorphisms.

Too long for a comment.
If $\pi\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is monic irreducible, let $C_\pi$ be the corresponding companion matrix.
Fact. We have $\mu_M=\pi$ if and only if $M$ is similar to the block diagonal matrix $M_\pi:=\begin{pmatrix} C_\pi & & \cr & \ddots & \cr & & C_\pi\end{pmatrix}.$
To prove this, you can either use Frobenius decomposition, or procced as follows: setting $L=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(\pi)$, the map $(\bar{P},v)\in L\times\mathbb{Q}^n\mapsto P(M)(v)\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ endows the abelian group $\mathbb{Q}^n$ with a structure of a finite dimensional $L$-vector space. If $(v_1,\ldots,v_r)$ is an $L$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}^n$, then one may show that, if $d=\deg(\mu)$, then  $\mathcal{B}=(\bar{X}^{i-1} v_j)_{1\leq i\leq d, 1\leq j\leq r}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}^n$. One easily check, that if $u$ is the endomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ whose matrix wrt the canonical basis is $M$, then the matrix of $u$ wrt to $\mathcal{B}$ is $M_\pi$, and we are done.
It follwos that the set of matrices of $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ coming from a number field is the disjoint union of the conjugacy classes of $M_\pi$, where $\pi$ runs through the set of monic irreducible polynomials of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.
I suspect that it should be easy to prove that this set have density $1$ from here, but this is not my area of expertise...
